# What does 撥の音も加えた gliss. mean? (in sheet music)

Tags: translation, music

I am a musician playing the Marimba. Because quite a bit of music for marimba is written by famous Japanese composers, occasionally I come across some Japanese text I would like to understand.

In the piece "Two methods of Movement for Marimba", written by Toshimitsu TANAKA, there is, on the 6th page, a Glissando (moving with the sticks along all bars) with a star. At the bottom of the page, the star is printed again, this time with a note in Japanese.

[image: gliss]

[image: note]

(Full images: [glissando](http://imageshack.us/a/img59/2897/p1050958x.jpg) & [note](http://imageshack.us/a/img198/9558/p1050957.JPG).)

> ★撥の音も加えた*gliss.*

I would be very grateful if someone could unveil the meaning of that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads: "[撥]{ばち}の[音]{おと}も[加]{くわ}えた*gliss*".
This literally means: "The sound of drumsticks"-too "added to"-gliss, and in translation:

`Glissando complemented by the sound of drumsticks.`

It seems a bit rendundant, knowing that a Marimba would only allow for discrete  glissando.

Comment: Could it mean sliding the mallet *shaft* as well, rather than just the wrapped part?  If so, then I think it wouldn't be redundant.

Comment: Hmm... very interesting. This might be the case. Something that also hints to this are the X-shaped notes on the Glissando, normally used on 'hard' hits in percussion like when hitting a cymbal or a cowbell. Thanks a lot, Jens and snailplane!